# How to ensure HighStocks chart x-axis spans the full chart width?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using HighStocks (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) and have data being plotted on 2 different y axes with timestamps for the x axis, one series is an 'areaspline' chart and the other is a 'column' chart. When changing the zoom view, the chart becomes more or less narrow. This never happened when I was only using areasplines, even with two y-axes.

How can I ensure the x-axis fills the entire chart width?

[image: 3 hr zoom view -- still not full width]
[image: 1 day zoom view -- very narrow chart]

Comment: Can you recreate this as live demo, i.e as jsfiddle.net.

Comment: can you reproduce the same in any thing like jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Please provide your code